# C++ beginner question regarding chars

Tags: c++

I'm just messing around with some C++ at the moment trying to make a simple tic-tac-toe game and I'm running into a bit of a problem. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Square {
public:
    char getState() const;
    void setState(char);
    Square();
    ~Square();
private:
    char * pState;
};

class Board {
public:
    Board();
    ~Board();
    void printBoard() const;
    Square getSquare(short x, short y) const;
private:
    Square board[3][3];
};

int main() {
    Board board;
    board.getSquare(1,2).setState('1');
    board.printBoard();
    return 0;
}

Square::Square() {
    pState = new char;
    *pState = ' ';
}
Square::~Square() {
    delete pState;
}
char Square::getState() const {
    return *pState;
}
void Square::setState(char set) {
    *pState = set;
}

Board::~Board() {

}
Board::Board() {

}
void Board::printBoard() const {
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        cout << "|";
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            cout << board[x][y].getState();
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
}
Square Board::getSquare(short x, short y) const {
    return board[x][y];
}
```

Forgive me if there are blatantly obvious problems with it or it's stupidly written, this is my first program in C++ :p However, the problem is that when I try and set the square 1,2 to the char '1', it doesn't print out as a 1, it prints out as some strange character I didn't recognise.

Can anyone tell me why? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was there a reason you need to use a `char *` on the heap instead of a normal `char` on the stack?

Comment: This isn't really a solution for your problem, but why are you dynamically allocating the state of each Square? Why not just have a single char field? Also, your getSquare should return a reference to a square, not return it by value.

Comment: Xavier: Was just trying something new.

Uri: I honestly have no idea. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You don't need to use `new` for creating instances of variables.
2. Try changing your state variable to `char` instead of `char *` (pointer to `char`).
3. In general, the `char *` type is used to indicate a collection (array) of characters terminated by a nul character.
4. Also, `set` is a data type in the `std` namespace.  Just change the name to something else, such as `new_value`.
5. The `getState()` method is returning a **copy** of the state, not a reference to the state.  This where Java and C++ differ.  Try returning a `State&`, which is C++ jargon for a reference to a State instance.
6. Your program is a bit overkill for a Tic-Tac-Toe game; the *ancient ones* used arrays of `char` instead of this new fashioned stuff called OO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D

I know that doing an OO version of Tic-Tac-Toe is a little overkill but I'm just trying to get used to the language and its intricacies.

Comment: @Sam, point #4 is an excellent example of why you should avoid `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 5):

The `Board::getSquare` method is returning a *copy* of the `Square` object.  The `pState` variable of the copied `Square` object points to the same character as the original `Square` object.  When the copied `Square` object is destroyed, it deletes the `char` object pointed to by the `pState` variable.  This invalidates the `char` object in the `Square` object in the `Board`.  When you go to print, you are printing an invalid `char` object.

As others has stated, the `pState` variable should probably be a `char` rather than a `char*`.  This will move you a step forward in resolving your issues.  You still need to deal with returning a reference to the `Square` object rather than a copy of the `Square` object.

Answer (score 3):

```
Square Board::getSquare(short x, short y) const {
    return board[x][y];
}
```

In here, you are returing a **copy** of the Square instance. Since there is no **copy constructor**, the instance will be copied by memory value. So now there are 2 Square instances which the state points to the same value.

But a Square has a **destructor**. In the destructor, the state pointer is deleted. But then the remaining copy now owns a dangling pointer.

1. Square instance *A* is created.
2. Char pointer *pA* is allocated and set to `' '` as *A* is created.

   ```
   +-----+
   | pA -----> ' '
   +-----+
   ```
3. Temporary Square instance *B* is bit-copied from *A* in `getSquare`. That means its char pointer *pB* points to the same location of *pA*

   ```
   +-----+        
   | pA -----> ' '
   +-----+      ^
   +-----+      |
   | pB --------'
   +-----+
   ```
4. Square instance *B* is setState to `'1'`, so the content of pB is changed to `'1'`

   ```
   +-----+        
   | pA -----> '1'
   +-----+      ^
   +-----+      |
   | pB --------'
   +-----+  *pB='1'
   ```
5. The temporary Square instance *B* is destroyed because, well, it's temporary.

   ```
   +-----+        
   | pA -----> garbage
   +-----+      ^
   + - - +      |
   : pB --------'
   + - - +  delete pB
   ```
6. Now *pA* points to garbage.

   ```
   +-----+        
   | pA -----> garbage
   +-----+
   ```

---

You should return a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29) to avoid copying,

```
Square& Board::getSquare(short x, short y) { return board[x][y]; }
//----^ "&" means reference. Similar to pointer, but not rebindable/nullable. 
//      Just think of it as a read-only pointer without needing a "*"

const Square& Board::getSquare(short x, short y) const { return board[x][y]; }
// Both mutable and const versions are needed. (Yes, code duplication.)
```

and/or provide a copy constructor.

```
class Square {
public:
  ...
  Square(const Square&);

...
Square::Square(const Square& other) {
  pState = new char;
  *pState = *other.pState;
}
```

---

You can just use

```
class Square {
public:
    char getState() const;  // { return state; }
    void setState(char);    // { state = input; }
private:
    char state;
};
```

to avoid messing with heap memories. `cout <<` supports printing a `char`.

And please don't write C++ in Java.

Comment: My first language was Java so forgive the transition ^_^

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you for the explanation! Like I said, still pretty new to all of this.

Another question: The getState() method is returning a copy of the char, right? Could I change it to return a pointer to it? And if I did, would that increase efficiency? (I know it's just 60 odd lines of code but I'm interested to know:))

Thanks.

Comment: @Samwhoo: You *must* change it to a pointer (or better, a reference) because you want to change the original value, not a copy. See update on how. (Return by pointer (reference) or value won't affect efficiency much due to return-value elision (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).)

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

<s>1) The `getSquare` method is `const` and so returns a `const` object.</s>

1) The `getSquare` method is `const` and so cannot return a non-`const` reference to a const object.

2) The object returned from `getSquare` is a copy of the square in the board.

To fix:

1) Remove the `const` from the `getSquare` method.

2) alter `getSquare` to return a reference: `Square & Board::getSquare(short x, short y)`

Comment: Although it's good practice to only return const references from const methods, adding the cont qualifier does not affect the return type.

Comment: @John Gordon: g++ gives me `invalid initialization of reference of type 'Square&' from expression of type 'const Square'` so basically yes it does because you're telling the method that `this` is `const` and thus you cannot initialize a non-const reference to it.

Comment: That's because you're trying to use a const reference as a non-const one, not because the return type is altered by a method qualifier. Consider a method that returned a reference to something other than *this or a member variable, a static member for example.

Comment: I should probably not pretend I know C++ in that case.

Comment: Hang on... I never said the return type was altered by a method qualifier. I said you cannot initialize a non const reference using a const. Or am I still missing something?